# What are all the types available in Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, cython

During a Cython meetup a speaker pointed to other data types such as `cython.ssize_t`. The type `ssize_t` is briefly mentioned in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Size_and_pointer_difference_types) however it is not well explained. Similarly Cython documentation mentions types in terms of how types are [automatically converted](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#automatic-type-conversions).

What are all the data types available in Cython and what are their specifications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have basically access to most of the C types:

Here are the equivalent of all the Python types (if I do not miss some), taken from Oreilly book `cython book`

Python `bool`:

- bint (boolean coded on 4 bits, alias for short)

Python `int` and `long`

- [unsigned] char
- [unsigned] short
- [unsigned] int
- [unsigned] long
- [unsigned] long long

Python `float`

- float
- double
- long double

Python `complex`

- float complex
- double complex

Python `bytes` / `str` / `unicode`

- char *
- std::string

For the `size_t` and `Py_ssite_t`, keep in mind these are aliases.

`Py_ssize_t` is defined in [`python.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f684d83d86e1990784816d4b243d724e6ab8304f/Include/Python.h) imported implicitly in cython. That can hold the size (in bytes) of the largest object the Python interpreter ever creates.

While `size_t` is a standard C89 type, defined in [`<stddef.h>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stddef.h).